# Publish java library with custom primary artifact

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I m trying to create a java library with custom primary artifact..
I followed this [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_overview.html#sec:publishing_custom_primary_artifact), but the problem is when i run the "publish" task, i get this error.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':publishMavenPublicationToMyRepoRepository'.
> Task with path 'rpm' not found in root project 'commons'.
```

This is my gradle file :

```
import com.netflix.gradle.plugins.rpm.Rpm

plugins {
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
    id("nebula.ospackage") version "7.4.1"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
}

group = "com.test"
version = "1.0.0"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")
    implementation("com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.10.14")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.9")
}

tasks.withType<Rpm> {
    version = "1.0.0"
    release = "1"
    packageName = "com.test.commons"
    into("$buildDir/rpms/com.test.commons.rpm")
}

val rpmFile = file("$buildDir/rpms/com.test.commons.rpm")
val rpmArtifact = artifacts.add("archives", rpmFile) {
    type = "rpm"
    builtBy("rpm")
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            artifact(rpmArtifact)
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "myRepo"
            url = uri("file://${buildDir}/repo")
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the rpm task, how can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

The `rpm` task type is available with the `nebula.rpm` plugin as explained in the wiki [here](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/RPM-Plugin)

```
plugins {
    id("nebula.ospackage") version "7.4.1"
    id("nebula.rpm") version "7.4.1"
}
```

Not familiar with this plugin, but it doesn't look like applying `nebula.ospackage` is enough.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. i tried your solution but i always get the some error

Answer (score 0):

The `nebula.ospackage` plugin will create a task named `buildRpm` of type `com.netflix.gradle.plugins.rpm.Rpm`.

In your script you reference a task by the name `rpm`, which does not exists : this explains the error you got (`> Task with path 'rpm' not found in root project 'commons'.`)

Just update your script to use correct task name :

```
val rpmArtifact = artifacts.add("archives", rpmFile) {
    type = "rpm"
    builtBy("buildRpm") // <=== instead of "rpm"
}
```

*Note* : you don't have to apply plugin `nebula.rpm`, `nebula.ospackage` is enough.